# Unable to save weights while using pre-trained VGG16 model

Tags: deep-learning, keras

While using the pre-trained VGG16 model I am unable to save the weights of the best model. I use this code:

```
checkpointer = [
                # Stop if the accuracy is not improving after 7 iterations
                EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, verbose=1),
                # Saving the best model and re-use it while prediction 
                ModelCheckpoint(filepath="C:/Users/skumarravindran/Documents/keras_save_model/vgg16_v1.hdf5", verbose=1, monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True),
                #            
]
```

And I get the following error:

> C:\Users\skumarravindran\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\py35gpu1\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py:405: RuntimeWarning: Can save best model only with val_acc available, skipping.
>     'skipping.' % (self.monitor), RuntimeWarning)

Comment: Do you have `metrics=['acc']` in your `model.compile()` line?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced two situations where this error arises:

1. introducing a custom metric
2. using multiple outputs

In both cases the `acc` and `val_acc` are not computed. Strangely, Keras does compute an overall `loss` and `val_loss`.

You can remedy the first situation by adding `accuracy` to the metrics but that may have side effects, I am not sure. In both cases however, you can add `acc` and `val_acc` yourself in a callback. I have added an example for the multi output case where I have created a custom callback in which I compute my own `acc` and `val_acc` results by averaging over all val's and val_acc's of the output layers.

I have a model having are 5 dense output layers at the end, labeled D0..D4. The output of one epoch is as follows:

```
3540/3540 [==============================] - 21s 6ms/step - loss: 14.1437 - 
D0_loss: 3.0446 - D1_loss: 2.6544 - D2_loss: 3.0808 - D3_loss: 2.7751 -
D4_loss: 2.5889 - D0_acc: 0.2362 - D1_acc: 0.3681 - D2_acc: 0.1542 - D3_acc: 0.1161 - 
D4_acc: 0.3994 - val_loss: 8.7598 - val_D0_loss: 2.0797 - val_D1_loss: 1.4088 - 
val_D2_loss: 2.0711 - val_D3_loss: 1.9064 - val_D4_loss: 1.2938 - 
val_D0_acc: 0.2661 - val_D1_acc: 0.3924 - val_D2_acc: 0.1763 - 
val_D3_acc: 0.1695 - val_D4_acc: 0.4627
```

As you can see it outputs an overall `loss` and `val_loss` and for each output layer: Di_loss, Di_acc, val_Di_loss and val_Di_acc, for i in 0..4. All of this is the content of the `logs` dictionary which is transmitted as a parameter in `on_epoch_begin` and `on_epoch_end` of a callback. Callbacks have more event handlers but for our purpose these two are the most relevant. When you have 5 outputs (as in my case) then the size of the dictionary is 5 times 4(acc, loss, val_acc, val_loss) + 2 (loss+val_loss).

What I did is compute the average of all accuracies and validation accuracies to add two items to `logs`:

```
logs['acc'] = som_acc / n_accs
logs['val_acc'] = som_val_acc / n_accs
```

Be sure you add this callback **before** the checkpoint callback, else the extra information you provide will not bee 'seen'. If all is implemented correctly the error message does not appear anymore and the model is happily checkpointing. 
The code of my callback for the multiple output case is provided below.

```
    class ExtraLogInfo(keras.callbacks.Callback):
        def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs):
            self.timed = time.time()

            return

        def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
            print(logs.keys())
            som_acc = 0.0
            som_val_acc = 0.0
            n_accs = (len(logs) - 2) // 4
            for i in range(n_accs):
                acc_ptn = 'D{:d}_acc'.format(i)
                val_acc_ptn = 'val_D{:d}_acc'.format(i)
                som_acc += logs[acc_ptn]
                som_val_acc += logs[val_acc_ptn]

            logs['acc'] = som_acc / n_accs
            logs['val_acc'] = som_val_acc / n_accs
            logs['time'] = time.time() - self.timed

            return
```

Answer (score 0):

By using following code you will be able to save best model based on accuracy.

Please use following code:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer= 'adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
    steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0] // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=[ModelCheckpoint('VGG16-transferlearning.model', monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True)]
)
```

Comment: Not when using a custom metric or a multi output model.