# Keras callbacks keep skip saving checkpoints, claiming val_acc is missing

Tags: python-3.x, keras, checkpointing

I'll run some larger models and want to try intermediate results.

Therefore, I try to use checkpoints to save the best model after each epoch.

This is my code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(700, input_shape=(X_modified.shape[1], X_modified.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(700, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(700))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(Y_modified.shape[1], activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Save the checkpoint in the /output folder
filepath = "output/text-gen-best.hdf5"

# Keep only a single checkpoint, the best over test accuracy.
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath,
                            monitor='val_acc',
                            verbose=1,
                            save_best_only=True,
                            mode='max')
model.fit(X_modified, Y_modified, epochs=100, batch_size=50, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

But I am still getting the warning after the first epoch:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py:432: RuntimeWarning: Can save best model only with val_acc available, skipping.
  'skipping.' % (self.monitor), RuntimeWarning)
```

To add `metrics=['accuracy']` to the model was in other SO questions (e.g. [Unable to save weights while using pre-trained VGG16 model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46438247/unable-to-save-weights-while-using-pre-trained-vgg16-model?rq=1)) the solution, but here the error still remains.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are trying to checkpoint the model using the following code

```
# Save the checkpoint in the /output folder
filepath = "output/text-gen-best.hdf5"

# Keep only a single checkpoint, the best over test accuracy.
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath,
                            monitor='val_acc',
                            verbose=1,
                            save_best_only=True,
                            mode='max')
```

`ModelCheckpoint` will consider the argument `monitor` to take the decision of saving the model or not. In your code it is `val_acc`. So it will save the weights if there is a increase in the `val_acc`.

Now in your fit code,

```
model.fit(X_modified, Y_modified, epochs=100, batch_size=50, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

you haven't provided any validation data. `ModelCheckpoint` can't save the weights because it don't have the `monitor` argument to check.

In order to do check pointing based on `val_acc` you must provide some validation data like this.

```
model.fit(X_modified, Y_modified, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid), epochs=100, batch_size=50, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

If you don't want to use validation data for whatever be the reason and implement check pointing, you have to change the `ModelCheckpoint` to work based on `acc` or `loss` like this

```
# Save the checkpoint in the /output folder
filepath = "output/text-gen-best.hdf5"

# Keep only a single checkpoint, the best over test accuracy.
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath,
                            monitor='acc',
                            verbose=1,
                            save_best_only=True,
                            mode='max')
```

Keep in mind that you have to change `mode` to `min` if you are going to `monitor` the `loss`

Comment: OK, that's embarrassing. There was one little moment I was wondering about the `val` in `val_acc`, but headed back to compare 2 long days other code, except the fit method.
Thanks, it works!

Comment: @xentity Happy to hear it helped

Answer (score 1):

It is missing, not because the metric is missing, but because you have no validation data. Add some through the `validation_data` parameter to `fit`, or use `validation_split`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, just edit 'val_acc' to 'val_accuracy'

Answer (score 0):

you just have to change `monitor='val_acc'` to -> `monitor='val_accuracy'`

as your metrics is `metrics=['accuracy']`