# Keras callback ModelCheckpoint doesn't save weights

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Solution suggested here did not solve my problem [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52776622/keras-callbacks-keep-skip-saving-checkpoints-claiming-val-acc-is-missing).

I'm trying to use callbacks `ModelCheckpoint` and EarlyStopping to save the best weights when early stopping. After the first epoch I get a runtime warning but the codes runs the remaining epochs without errors, but still no file containing weight appears. The warning after the first epoch is the following:

> RuntimeWarning: Can save best model only with val_acc available,
>   skipping.   'skipping.' % (self.monitor), RuntimeWarning) 
>   RuntimeWarning: Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_acc` which
>   is not available. Available metrics are:
>   val_loss,val_accuracy,loss,accuracy   (self.monitor,
>   ','.join(list(logs.keys()))), RuntimeWarning

I have validation data added to the `fit()` function so I'm not sure why.

```
filepath = "weights_best.hdf5"

model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",
                  metrics=['accuracy'],
                  optimizer=optimizer)
batchSize = 64 
numEpochs = 75
validation_data = (data.x_valid, data.y_valid)

callbackCheckpoint = keras.callbacks.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath,
                                                                   monitor='val_acc',
                                                                   save_best_only=True,
                                                                   save_weights_only= True,
                                                                   mode='max')

callbackEarlyStop = keras.callbacks.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc',
                                                                min_delta=0,
                                                                patience=7,
                                                                verbose=0,
                                                                mode='auto')
callbacks = [callbackCheckpoint, callbackEarlyStop]
model.fit(data.x_train, data.y_train, batchSize, numEpochs, callbacks=callbacks,
              validation_data=validation_data)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the output when you run `fit`? If `val_acc` is there then I'd suggest you change the Keras and Tensorflow version, the code doesn't look like there's any problem.

Comment: At the end of each epoch it still outputs 
```45000/45000 [==============================] - 126s 3ms/step - loss: 0.1793 - accuracy: 0.0993 - val_loss: 0.1806 - val_accuracy: 0.0968```, so yes, ```val_acc``` is present! I'll give it a try.

Comment: Nooooooo, that's a `val_accuracy` not `val_acc`. Change that!!

Comment: Oh, they are different? What should I change?

Comment: `monitor='val_acc'` to `monitor='val_accuracy'` or `metrics=['accuracy']` to `metrics=['acc']`

Comment: What you're monitoring must be in the printed metrics when you call `fit`

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Feel free to add this as an answer so I can mark this question as solved!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `monitor='val_acc'` to `monitor='val_accuracy'` or `metrics=['accuracy']` to `metrics=['acc']`

Answer (score 0):

Yes monitor 'val_accuracy', Just a comment, monitoring and saving the weights based on the highest val_accuracy may not give you the "best" answer. Monitoring 'val_loss' is usually a better answer. val_loss and val_accuracy are calculated in entirely different ways. It is not uncommon to see the val_loss increase but have val_accuracy increase as well or vice versa. In the end you want to use a model with the lowest validation loss. If you do do that make sure to change mode='min' or mode='auto in the checkpoint callback.